# How do I delete a SharePoint file in Power Automate without knowing the ID?

Tags: sharepoint, automation, sharepoint-online, power-automate

I am using Power Automate Cloud with SharePoint Online and I want to delete a file where I know the file name, but I don't know the ID. The file is not the triggered file. Can this be done? I have tried to put the path in the File Identifier and it fails, but the run details looks good to me.

Below is the Power Automate job using SharePoint Delete file option.
[image]

Below is the Run Error for the job.

[image]

The file I want to delete is the exact path by combining Site Address and File Identifier. Is there a different way to do this?

I am able to use dynamic content because the trigger file has the same metadata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to URL Encode the `/`, replace it with `%2F`.

Example:

```
%2fDSS Approved%2fexample1.json
```

Alternatively, you could create a `Compose` step before hand, to build the path, then use the `encodeUriComponent(...)` function...

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! %2f did the trick! I will also keep the Compose function in my toolbelt... thanks!